# Difference between $u$ and $v$ as velocity variables in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, conventions, notation

I am beginning to learn about special relativity, so I apologize for the (most likely) basic question.

I frequently see, for example, the Lorentz Factor given by the equation $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$, which makes sense to me.  However, I also see it frequently written with a $u$ instead of $v$.  (I have also seen Lorentz Transformations and other equations with $u$ instead of $v$.)

**Within special relativity,** is there a conventional situation in which $u$ is used instead of $v$? Obviously, $u$ denotes some velocity, but is there a specific way in which it usually differs from $v$?

For example, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0602037.pdf) uses both $v$ and $u$ as velocities.  (The content of the paper is *way* too advanced for what I know about SR, but this is just an example of what I am talking about.)

I tried to search for an answer, but most of the things I found were about $u$ being used as an initial velocity, which I don't think applies to this situation.

---

Edit: I glanced at the [Wikipedia page for the relativistic velocity addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula), which said

> The notation employs $u$ as velocity of a body within a Lorentz frame S, and $v$ as velocity of a second frame S′, as measured in S, and $u′$ as the transformed velocity of the body within the second frame.

Is this the general convention?

Comment: There’s a missing square root on the right hand side of your expression for $\gamma$.

Comment: As always: different authors have different notation.

Comment: @robphy You're right! Thank you for catching that.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks for your response. I sort of expected that, but I thought there might be some convention since these two variables are used so often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many discussions of Special Relativity, there are *three* velocities: the velocity of an object in some reference frame, the velocity of the *same* object in some *other* reference frame (one that is moving relative to the first frame), and the relative velocity between the two frames.

These are often denoted as $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf u’$, and $\mathbf v$, or $\mathbf v$, $\mathbf v’$, and $\mathbf u$. Since there is no standard, you have to pay attention to what the meanings are.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer.  In the equation $p=\gamma mv$, I believe $v$ is $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$, where $x$ is the position as measured by an outside observer, and $t$ is the time as measured by that same observer.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Thank you for your help!